# Perform average and sum calculations on Several sheets in my workbook

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have several sheets with numeric data in columns B up to Column I, and and dates in column J. I've found and edited this macro which I thought would give me the averages and the totals of each column for all sheets. However all it seems to do is give me the total for Column I on each sheet. I'm quite new to VBA and I've got into a bit of a mess with this. I'm wondering if I'm making a basic mistake somewhere?

```
 Sub CalcOnSheets2()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Row As Integer
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim ActiveWorksheet As Long
Dim ThisWorksheet As Long
Dim N As Integer

Dim x As Integer
x = Sheets.Count

For N = 2 To x

lastrow = Sheets(N).Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
Sheets(N).range("a1:J" & lastrow + 3).Columns.AutoFit

If lastrow > 1 Then

For Row = 3 To lastrow

Sheets(N).range("B1:J" & lastrow + 3).NumberFormat = "£#,##0.00);(£#,##0.00)"

Next

Dim r As range, j As Long, k As Long, z As Long
j = Sheets(N).range("B2").End(xlToRight).Column

For k = 2 To j - 1

Set r = Sheets(N).range(Sheets(N).Cells(1, k), Sheets(N).Cells(1, k).End(xlDown))
r.End(xlDown).Offset(2, 0) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(r)
r.End(xlDown).Offset(3, 0) = WorksheetFunction.Average(r)
Next k


Else

MsgBox ("There is no data at column D")
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

range("A1").Select

Next N

End Sub
```

Comment: May I ask why you want to engage VBA to do what worksheet formulas do much faster?

Comment: The data comes into me  daily and a new row is added to each sheet each day so I was hoping that I could automate it

Comment: Formulas can do that. `=Average(Sheet2!A:A)`

Comment: The tables are dynamic. Sometimes they may have ten rows and sometimes they may have two rows. I wasn't sure that a formula would manage that

Comment: Since you're summing/averaging to the last row of data just sum / average the whole column. As I said above `=average(Sheet2!A:A)` All rows in column A will be averaged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed a few things. Your for loops weren't closing out correctly. Keep going on learning VBA! There are definitely easier ways to lick this problem, but hey this one seems to work so what the heck. Here is the updated code, hopefully it works for you...
Sub CalcOnSheets2()

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Row As Integer
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim ActiveWorksheet As Long
Dim ThisWorksheet As Long
Dim N As Integer

Dim r As Range, j As Long, k As Long, z As Long

Dim x As Integer
x = Sheets.Count

For N = 2 To x

  lastrow = Sheets(N).Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
  Sheets(N).Range("a1:J" & lastrow + 3).Columns.AutoFit
  
  If lastrow > 1 Then
  
    For Row = 3 To lastrow
      Sheets(N).Range("B1:I" & lastrow + 3).NumberFormat = "£#,##0.00;(£#,##0.00)"
    Next
    

    j = Sheets(N).Range("B2").End(xlToRight).Column
    
    For k = 2 To j - 1
      Set r = Sheets(N).Range(Sheets(N).Cells(1, k), Sheets(N).Cells(1, k).End(xlDown))
      r.End(xlDown).Offset(2, 0) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(r)
      r.End(xlDown).Offset(3, 0) = WorksheetFunction.Average(r)
    Next k
    
  Else
    MsgBox ("There is no data at column D")
  End If

  Range("A1").Select
Next N

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Comment: This seems to give me the totals and averages as required, for which I'm very grateful. However it does create a runtime error 1004  Application-defined or object-defined error. When I run the debug, the highlighted line is r."End(xlDown).Offset(2, 0) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(r)"

Comment: When checking your code, I threw some random numbers in excel to roughly replicate your description and it worked. Without your numbers it's hard to know what might be causing it. However, I did notice a couple things that I adjusted for you. The column selection for formatting went to column j. But you only want to format through column i, so I changed that. without your numbers I won't be able to help you. here is the updated code:

Answer (score 0):

A little simplified:

```
Sub CalcOnSheets2()
    
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim k As Long, r As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    
        lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
        ws.Range("A1:J" & lastrow + 3).Columns.AutoFit
    
        If lastrow > 1 Then
            ws.Range("B1:J" & lastrow + 3).NumberFormat = "£#,##0.00;(£#,##0.00)"
            For k = 2 To ws.Range("B2").End(xlToRight).Column - 1
                Set r = ws.Range(ws.Cells(k, 1), ws.Cells(k, lastrow))
                ws.Cells(lastrow + 2, k) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(r)
                ws.Cells(lastrow + 3, k) = WorksheetFunction.Average(r)
            Next k
        Else
            MsgBox ("There is no data at column D")
        End If
    
    Next ws
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```